# Trajectory(linerenderer) of a planet doesn't reflect the actual motion Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to recreate a solar system and i'm using newton's law. The actual force works great but when i try to "predict" the path of a planet it just doesn't work: to predict it i use a lineRenderer whose points get placed on the position at the Tth instant ( T being time ). When i start the game they are close but as time passes the planet actually goes in "orbit" while the line shoots up.
I can't understand why this happens seen that i calculate the planet's position in the same way as the line's one. I also tried instantiating a ball but same result.

```
public void UpdateSpeed(Vector3 acceleration,float time)
{
    velocity += acceleration * time;
}

public void UpdatePosition(float time)
{
    transform.position +=velocity *time;
}

public void UpdateLine(float time)
{
    position += velocity * time;
    Debug.Log(position);
    Instantiate(ball, position, Quaternion.identity);
    line.positionCount++;
    line.SetPosition(line.positionCount-1, position);
}
```

and here the function that computes acceleration

```
 public Vector3 CalculateAcceleration(GameObject subj, float time)
{
    Vector3 Acceleration = Vector3.zero;
    foreach (var pl in planets)
    {
        if (pl != subj)
        {
            float sqrDistance= Mathf.Pow(Vector3.Distance(subj.transform.position, pl.transform.position), 2);
            Vector3 direction = (pl.transform.position - subj.transform.position).normalized;
            Acceleration += direction * (pl.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass * GravitationalConstant)/sqrDistance;
        }
    }
    return Acceleration;
}
```

is the rigidbody attached to the planet making a difference for the position?

Comment: This sounds like floating point errors to me. 
With floating point maths repeated calculations all at once can have a different value to the same calculation done discretely

Comment: I thought the same thing but then why does the rigidbody actually follow the orbit? Does it have an approximation function? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so as often happens i'm an idiot. I was calculating in the acceleration function distances with the actual bodies positions instead of the simulated position so i always had a false value that was increasing instead of varying

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with the orbit, calculate the OrbitFirst then call it to move your object with different time, just modify delta time below

```
LineRenderer lr; 

//Build the orbit path/line
void CalculateOrbitEllipse()
{
    Vector3[] points = new Vector3[segments + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < segments; i++)
    {
        Vector2 position2D = orbitPath.Evaluate((float)i / (float)segments);
        points[i] = new Vector3(position2D.x, 0f, position2D.y);
    }
    points[segments] = points[0];

    lr.positionCount = segments + 1;
    lr.SetPositions(points);
}


//make the planet move, 
//you can invoke this using your time variable, Time.deltaTime see below
IEnumerator AnimationOrbit()
{
    if (orbitPeriod < 0.1f)
    {
        orbitPeriod = 0.1f;
    }
    float orbitSpeed = 0.1f / orbitPeriod;
    while (orbitActive)
    {
        orbitProgress += Time.deltaTime * orbitSpeed;
        orbitProgress %= 1f;
        SetOrbitingObjectPosition();
        lr = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        CalculateOrbitEllipse();
        yield return null;
    }
 }


 void SetOrbitingObjectPosition()
 {
    Vector2 orbitPos = orbitPath.Evaluate(orbitProgress);
    orbitingObject.localPosition = new Vector3(orbitPos.x, 0, orbitPos.y);        
 }
```

Comment: if i understood correctly, you're saying to create an orbit and then move the planet on it, but my goal is, using newton's law, to show a preview of the orbit that changes as you change one of the planets' masses or gravitational constant. My issue is that the preview is not correct even if i do the exact same steps as in the function for the actual movement

Comment: ohh i see that was not clear to me. I suspect changing the mass, would mean a completely new orbit and not an incremental change. The only thing _overlapping trajectory point_ is the _last point of trajectory becomes your first_ point of the new trajectory with the new mass. But it would be completely redrawn. The problem is the inertia of the new mass is not the same as the old mass, and together their inertia is different. Is this what you are getting at?

Comment: no the problem is not in the change but in the trajectory itself. If i change mass it re-draws the trajectory from the start but the problem is that the drawing is wrong(but from the start even with no mass change). imagine a line that is slowly  being drawn (wrongly, it goes up after a bit instead of closing on itself like an orbit) but when i start the simulation the planet actually goes around the other planet and stays in orbit. to sum up the trajectory doesn't reflect the actual movement of the planet

Comment: can you try to remove acceleration for now, and 1) refactor your code with a simple function such as `CalculateTheOrbit(decimal pos, decimal deltaMass)`  dont change mass yet. I see you are updating position in a couple of different places which could also be the issue and making it hard to track down. 2) set a _watch point_ on position. With the simplified function you should be able to see who is throwing your position off

Comment: Glad my comment on refactoring, the position/acceleration helped you!